# Is it even possible to tag photos in Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm reading wildly different things about tagging photos on Facebook.

1. One article says you can send `tags=array(...tag_uid...)` at the same time as you post the photo: [Tagging photos on Facebook with Graph API / PHP SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174527/)
2. One article said you can tag, but **first** you have to post to photo, and **then** set tags afterwards. (Can't remember the page)
3. One article said you can tag, but only one tag per request, so you have to iterate over the array. (Can't remember the page)
4. One article says you can't tag at all: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/371/

Does anyone know if tagging actually possible, and what is the correct way of doing it as of the current date?

Comment: Have you read this about [Photo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/)??

Answer (score 1):

You must get Photo ID firs and then tag someone on this photo

1. upload photo to album

   $photo_details = array(
       'message' => $message,
       'access_token' => $token
   );

   $photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath($file);

   $uploaded_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
2. Get Photo ID

   $photo_id = $uploaded_photo['id'];
3. set Friend ID you want to tag

   $tags = array(
           array('tag_uid' => $friend_id, 'x' => rand() % 100, 'y' => rand() % 100 )
       );
4. tag friend

   $facebook->api('/'.$photo_id.'/tags', 'post', array('tags'=>$tags));

It works for me, I hope this will help you

Comment: With your suggestion I get a "param tags must be an array" error. But by reading the official documentation carefully, I was able to make it work: `https://graph.facebook.com/$photo_id/tags?to=$friend_id&x=$x&y=$y&access_token=$token`. Also, an awful PHP/cURL bug set me back a while. If you specify CURLOPT_POST *after* CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, Facebook responds with a HTML page saying "Something went wrong". Damn swedes.